# How to use a Type variable to cast an object or instantiate a generic class?

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, reflection

Is it possible to do the following in C#?

```
Type myType = typeof(string);
var s1 = new List<myType>(); //s1 would be List<string>
var s2 = (myType) getObject(); //s2 would be string
```

I've tried a bunch of ways but they all end up either eventually requiring T (for `var myVar = (T) getObject();` or `new List<T>()`. I'm trying to do this without having any T. Only having the type info in a Type variable.

Comment: Create a method with different parameter lists like MyMethod(string s), MyMethod(int i) than depending on type a different method will be used.

Comment: @TimSchmelter im deserializing json into an object using newtonsoft `object DeserializeObject(string value, Type type);` I get my type from the DB (stored along with the json).

Comment: @NabeelFarooqui: ok, then the duplicate should help you